# How do I get Excel to auto select most recent week using time slicer in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel that is auto updated daily with previous day's sales information.  This report has time slicers to select different weeks within the year.  Currently, once the excel is opened, it is refreshed, saved as a new excel and then emailed.  The issue I am having is that once the excel contains data for a new week, the original week that was selected is still being displayed.  I would like to use VBA to automatically select the newest slicer.

I've done some research and found some code that other users said work however it did not work for me:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Week")
        n = .SlicerItems.Count

        For i = 1 To n - 1
            .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
        Next i

        .SlicerItems(n).Selected = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Also tried this piece of code which also did not work for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim today As Date
    today = Now
    Dim todayString As String
    todayString = Format$(today, "d mmm yyyy")
    Dim item As SlicerItem

    For Each item In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Week").SlicerItems
        If item.Name = todayString Then
            item.Selected = True
        Else
            item.Selected = False
        End If
    Next item

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

the above code refreshes pivot tables, saves, and then auto closes the excel.  What can I add to it to automatically select the most current time slicer?

Comment: Find your max (newest) value from the source data, then loop through the `slicercachelevel.sliceritem`s and select the one with the equivalent name

Comment: Can you provide the expected week string to match ?

Answer (score 0):

so the following was provided by another user from another forum and in case anyone is dealing with a similar situation, I would like to post the code that worked for me:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 SVAL = Format(Date, "ww")
 SVAL = Format(Date, "YYYY") & SVAL 

 With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_slicername")
     .ClearManualFilter
     For Each oSlicerItem In .SlicerItems
         If oSlicerItem.Name = SVAL Then
             oSlicerItem.Selected = True
         Else
             oSlicerItem.Selected = False
         End If
     Next oSlicerItem
 End With
 End Sub
```